# How do I get IntelliJ IDEA to align adjacent variable assignments on the "=" sign?

Tags: intellij-idea

Environment is IntelliJ IDEA 12.

I've got `Wrapping and Braces > Assignment Statement > Align when multiline` ticked. When I have adjacent properties, they're aligned correctly:

```
private final CustomerFactory  customerFactory  = FactoryBuilder.getDefaultCustomerFactory ( );
private final RepFactory       repFactory       = FactoryBuilder.getDefaultRepFactory ( );
private final WarehouseFactory warehouseFactory = FactoryBuilder.getDefaultWarehouseFactory ( );
```

but when I've got adjacent variable assignments, they're not:

```
final Integer account30 = parseCurrency ( fields.get ( FIELD_OVERDUE_BALANCE_1 ) );
final Integer account60 = parseCurrency ( fields.get ( FIELD_OVERDUE_BALANCE_2 ) );
final Integer account90 = parseCurrency ( fields.get ( FIELD_OVERDUE_BALANCE_3 ) );
final Integer account120 = parseCurrency ( fields.get ( FIELD_OVERDUE_BALANCE_4 ) );
final Integer priceNumber = parseInteger ( fields.get ( FIELD_PRICE_NUMBER ), 1 );
```

This is minor but it annoys me. Can anyone tell me what I can do to get these adjacent variable declarations aligned? What I want is:

```
final Integer account30   = parseCurrency ( fields.get ( FIELD_OVERDUE_BALANCE_1 ) );
final Integer account60   = parseCurrency ( fields.get ( FIELD_OVERDUE_BALANCE_2 ) );
final Integer account90   = parseCurrency ( fields.get ( FIELD_OVERDUE_BALANCE_3 ) );
final Integer account120  = parseCurrency ( fields.get ( FIELD_OVERDUE_BALANCE_4 ) );
final Integer priceNumber = parseInteger ( fields.get ( FIELD_PRICE_NUMBER ), 1 );
```

Answer (score 47):

You can also do this using built-in key bindings without any changes to Intellij options:

[image: How to align any text using keyboard strokes in Intelli]

**How this is done:**

Use the following (or equivalent) `GNOME` key bindings:

1. Highlight the first `=` (or any delimiter of your choosing)
2. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> once for each additional <kbd>=</kbd> to `Add Selection for Next Occurrence`
3. Press <kbd>Left</kbd> once then *make room* by pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> per the above GIF
4. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> to *enter* `Column Selection mode`
5. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> again to *exit* `Column Selection mode` (notice selection is aligned).
6. Press <kbd>Left</kbd> twice then presss <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> to select all white space to each <kbd>=</kbd>
7. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> to exclude `=` from selection
8. Press <kbd>Backspace</kbd> and that will cause all of the uneven whitespace to truncate

After backspacing to where you want the columns aligned, you should now have something like:

```
someVar           = someVal
someOtherVar      = someVal
someOtherOtherVar = someVal
```

The nice thing about this approach is it's general purpose; The above steps will align *any* text within whitespace so long as you choose a distinct delimiter each line contains only once, such as `=` in the example given.

As noted previously, this example was performed using `GNOME` key bindings. You are free to pick a different scheme in `Settings` > `Keymap`:
[image]

Comment: OMG this is awesome! MUST be the selected answer in my view <3

Comment: It only works when the first variable is the shortest.

Comment: @gekowa I have not experienced that limitation before but note that, as an alternative to step `5`, you can also manually draw a column of cursors while still in `Column Selection Mode`.

Comment: this helped me a lot in organizing my properties files! As we have company wide code formatting rules (not touching properties files), I cannot change the configuration as @RaphMclee proposed. But the "Alt+j" did the trick! I was not aware of this behaviour until now! perfect.

Comment: It won't help if you want to align the declarations only (there is no `=` sign) but kudos for the `Alt + J` shortcut! It's a life changer...

Comment: @SteliosAdamantidis I use 1 of 2 strategies for that: 1) If there is no equals sign but they all contain a common modifier (`final` as shown in OP) _or white space_ then select those. 2) Enter `Column Selection Mode` and draw a column through them all. Then, for either case above: Press `Home` to move the cursors to the start of each line, `Ctrl + Shift + Left` to select up to the previous newline of each line, `Ctrl + Shift + Right` to exclude that newline and select only white space leading up to each declaration. Now delete to align and add as much white space as you like for indentation.

Comment: But if I format the code it then reverts back.

Answer (score 42):

I think you should be using the **Field groups** => *Align in columns*

*Align when multiline* has some other effect that doesn't apply here.

[image]

Comment: That's already turned on. It affects class level fields (properties), not method level variables.

Comment: @Andrew I see, I think I misunderstood your question. It wasn't that clear to me. Maybe you should have had a simpler example using a class with fields and methods. Anyway there is a bug reported to JetBrains that addresses this but unfortunately it has been resolved as "Won't fix": http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-56947

Comment: Hmmm... thanks. That answers that then. I disagree — it should be fixed.

Comment: Comment on the issue, this might inspire devs to implement it.

Comment: In Android Studio 1.2.2, under Java -> Wrapping and Braces: I see "Group Declarations" instead of "Field Groups", which includes separate checkboxes for "Align fields in columns" and "Align variables in columns".  It's likely IntelliJ 13/14 looks like that also.

Answer (score 40):

Under "Code Style"->"Java" in the Tab "Wrapping and Braces" find following entry and tick "Align Variable in columns".
Done!

[image: Setting to align variable declaration]

Comment: This works in Java but not with other extensions like Groovy or Scala.

Answer (score 3):

To align adjacent variable assignments on the “=” sign, do this:

[image]