# Is there an align by : or , or = plug-in for IntelliJ (I miss this from Sublime Text)?

Tags: intellij-idea, sublimetext, intellij-plugin

Is there an align by : or , or = plug-in for IntelliJ (I miss this from Sublime Text)?

There are a number of plug-ins for IntelliJ, but I can't seem to find one that will align code around the characters ',' or ':', or '=' like the [plug-in for SublimeText](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/alignment) will.

Answer (score 1):

There is no one plug in for everything that works like AlignTab did for me in ST2.
Here is what I did for css/sass & JavaScript:

1. Open your Preferences
2. In The Project Settings open / list the items under Code Style
3. Select JavaScript and then select the **Other** tab
4. I used "Align object properties" **on colon**
5. I also checked **"align C-style comments"** since I use a Live Template for generating functions with doc strings already inserted and taxable to fill them out fast
6. List item

Now, when you add new things to your Js object (on a mac) you can Option + Command + L to bring up a modal window that lets you reprocess the file.

For CSS/Sass I did this:

1. Open your Preferences
2. In The Project Settings open / list the items under Code Style
3. Select CSS and then select **Other** tab
4. In the **Align values** drop down I chose **"On colon"** (w/ spaces after colon checked as well)

This option isn't available in the sass/less/scss Code Styles but we work mainly with sass here and when I Control + Option + L I get the dialog prompting me with options. My most common use is to run in on the whole file or select some text and then run Control + Option + L

FYI - if you haven't investigated Live Templates (and you generate lots of boilerplate for documentation purposes, testing e.g) I highly recommend you take the time to work them into your flow. You will be rewarded with time and money. Well, the time I can guarantee based solely on my experience so far.

Answer (score -1):

I changed Settings -> User, to these

```
{
    "alignment_chars": ["=",":"],
    "alignment_space_chars": ["=",":"],
}
```

Comment: Uh, dude, is this customization for Sublime?  The question is how to reproduce this setting in IntelliJ.

Answer (score -1):

make sure that you already install VAlign packages.

Then goto preferences > key Bindings - Users :

Then you can input this to the file with in []

```
{
    "keys" : ["super+\\"], "command": "align_tab",
    "args" : {"user_input" : ":/l1f"}
}
```

Usage: command+\ (tested in mac - sublime text 3)

NOTE: It will align all : unless it is in next 2 rows (line space)

reference: https://github.com/randy3k/AlignTab

Hope this will help.

Comment: Nobody reads the title, I guess.  This is for sublime not intelliJ right?

Comment: oh, sorry for that, but i found this in other question raised in stackoverflow.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16272920/how-do-i-get-intellij-idea-to-align-adjacent-variable-assignments-on-the-sig

Hope this help though.