# How do I get IntelliJ IDEA to align all fields of a class?

Tags: intellij-idea

My question is somewhat similar to this one:
[How do I get IntelliJ IDEA to align adjacent variable assignments on the "=" sign?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16272920/how-do-i-get-intellij-idea-to-align-adjacent-variable-assignments-on-the-sig)

The only difference is that option aligns only when they are grouped. But I want **all** fields to be aligned, regardless the groups:

```
public class Clazz {

   Integer qaz;
   Integer wsx;

   final Integer qwe = 111;
   final Integer asd = 222;
   final Integer zxc = 333;

   final Integer tyutyu = 444;
   final Integer ghjghj = 555;
...
}
```

into

```
public class Clazz {

   Integer       qaz;
   Integer       wsx;

   final Integer qwe    = 111;
   final Integer asd    = 222;
   final Integer zxc    = 333;

   final Integer tyutyu = 444;
   final Integer ghjghj = 555;
...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible at the moment, but a feature request exists for this case: [IDEA-149359](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-149359).

Feel free to vote for it.